# Perform SQL query and then join

Tags: sql, sqlite, left-join

Lets say I have two tables:

- ticket with columns [id,date, userid] userid is a foreign key that references user.id
- user with columns [id,name]

Owing to really large tables I would like to first filter the tickets table by date

```
SELECT id FROM ticket WHERE date >= 'some date'
```

then I would like to do a left join with the user table. Is there a way to do it. I tried the follwoing but it doesnt work.

```
 select ticket.id, user.name from ticket where ticket.date >= '2015-05-18' left join user on ticket.userid=user.id;
```

Apologies if its a stupid question. I have searched on google but most answers involve subqueries after the join instead of what I want which is to perfrom the query first and then do the join for the items returned

To make things a little more clear, the problem I am facing is that I have large tables and join takes time. I am joining 3 tables and the query takes almost 3 seconds. Whats the best way to reduce time. Instead of joining and then doing the where clause, I figured I should first select a small subset and then join.

Comment: But your tables do not have columns in common.

Comment: not exactly sure what you are trying to do. Sub-query sounds like a right way to go if you first want to limit return set and later join it with something else. Also like @juergend pointed out two tables don't seem to have anything in common other than same name for a column.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  What is wrong with the query you showed us?  Does it give a syntax error?  Does it return incorrect results?  If the results are incorrect, what results did you get and what were you expecting?

Comment: I am not too familar with sqllite3. I just provided a bare minumum example. Let me make it more exhaustive

Comment: You may want to look into temp tables or CTEs, if you don't want to subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put everything in the right order:

select - from - where - group by - having - order by

```
select ticket.id, user.name 
from ticket left join user on ticket.user_id=user.id
where ticket.date >= '2015-05-18'
```

Or put it in a Derived Table:

```
select ticket.id, user.name 
from
 (
   select * from ticket
   where ticket.date >= '2015-05-18'
 ) as ticket 
left join user on ticket.user_id=user.id
```

Comment: Wouldnt this make the query time intensive. The problem I am facing is that I have large tables and join takes time. Instead of joining and then doing the where clause, I want to first select a small subset and then join. Thanks

Comment: @Fizi: A decent optimizer should create the same plan for both queries :-)